# Typing musical signs!

Tags: discussion

I've now found out simple ways of printing sharp, flat and natural signs for this site! At least, it works on my PC Windows.

Sharp is ampersand sharp semicolon. Flat is ampersand flat semicolon. Natural is ampersand natural semicolon.

`&sharp; &flat; &natural;` gives ♯ ♭ ♮
So there! So far, so good. So...

What are the tricks for diminished and half-diminished, and possibly other signs, that can be accessed easily on an ordinary qwertyboard?

This question will help us through 2019 when writing questions and answers in  both musical practice and theory. Happy New Year to all our readers and contributors!

Comment: Related: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/58314/are-there-unicode-characters-for-double-sharp-and-double-flat

Comment: That is great information. Thus it is possible to type a real sharp &sharp; instead of a hashtag #. Well it doesn't work in the comments as we can see in this comment, but I tested it as an answer without clicking on "Post Your Answer", and there it works great, so thanks for the info.

Comment: ...but what about double accidentals?

Comment: @mathlander  - double flats use the same methodology, double sharps will not. They get an 'x' just like they would on the music. Not a problem!

Answer (score 10):

`&deg;` is the named HTML entity for the (temperature or arc) degree symbol °, which [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminution#Diminished_chords) doubles as symbol for diminished chords.

For half-diminished chords you could use `<sup>&oslash;</sup>` (example: C<sup>ø</sup>).

`<sup>&#9651;</sup>` (example: C<sup>△</sup>) produces a symbol which can be used for a major seventh chord.

---

While `&sharp;`, `&flat;` and `&natural;` do work in post bodies, they don't work in comments and in question titles. But you *can* copy the Unicode characters from other posts and use them instead; all computer systems (including my old Moto E) render these correctly nowadays.

Answer (score 7):

This has little to do with the workings of the site. Just launch Charmap in Windows, find the sign you want to display and enter it using `&number;`.

For example °, which could be used to indicate diminished, just use `&0176;`. The number is shown bottom right in the Charmap tool. Depending on the selected font more or less characters are available.

I came across a website with a large list of music-related characters: https://www.alt-codes.net/music_note_alt_codes.php

Comment: If MeanGreen is correct, then `&sharp` `&flat` won't work from this iMac -- and they don't. Sorry, Tim, but you'll need to get the site admin to install some `markdown` commands.

Comment: This is ONLY for Windows -- not for MacOS and probably not for Linux

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - &sharp; etc work because they're recognised as html in an SE Q/A field, though not in a comment field - so the input OS is unimportant. The rest of your point regarding `alt codes` is perfectly valid - they are Windows-only.

Answer (score 3):

For systems with a <kbd>Compose</kbd> key, you can use that.

The <kbd>Compose</kbd> key is, by default:

- Debian & other X.Org systems: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>
- Windows: sometimes <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>; usually requires [another program](https://github.com/SamHocevar/wincompose) or [keyboard layout](http://www.kbdedit.com/manual/ex17_compose_key_chained_dead.html).

From there, you can type several symbols like so:

- ♯ <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>#</kbd> <kbd>#</kbd>
- ♭ <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>#</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd>
- ° <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd>

I find these rather intuitive.